# There exist $\langle A,R \rangle $ and $\langle B,S \rangle $ of order types $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with A and B disjoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As I have been,once again reading through the book of Herbert Enderton (which I am giving up due to unnecessary complications of later material) I came upon an ecercise which claims that

For any two order types $\alpha$ and $\beta$ there exist structures $\langle A,R \rangle$ and $\langle B , S \rangle $ members of order types $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$

I can not seem to prove it,and it is all confusing given the definition that an order type is an isomorphism type of linearly ordered structure,and that isomorphism type of structure X is set of structures such that they are isomorphic to X,and they are nor isomorphic to any structure of lesser rank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, and $f\colon X\to Y$ is a bijection, then any (say binary) relation $\leq$ on $X$ can be transferred into a relation on $Y$ via $f$.

> Define $\leq'$ on $Y$ as the relation $\{\langle f(u),f(v)\rangle\mid u\leq v\}$. Then we have that $u\leq v\iff f(u)\leq' f(v)$, and $f$ is a bijection. Therefore $\langle X,\leq\rangle$ and $\langle Y,\leq'\rangle$ are isomorphic.

Now show that given two sets $A$ and $B$, there are $A'$ and $B'$ such that $|A|=|A'|$ and $|B|=|B'|$ and $A'\cap B'=\varnothing$.

Comment: I can get sets of same cardinality but I can not make them belong to order type,since it requires to have the same rank as given set,basically I would take a cartesian product of A and {0} and cartesian product of B and {1},thus I would obtain disjointed sets,but then their rank increases and then they do not belong to the given order types according to given deffinition

Comment: But this is not a question of rank. It's a question of structure. You need to use the first part of the hint for that.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean,if you could furnish full proof please?

Comment: I've added more to the hint, not a full proof, but I think it should be enough.

Comment: Oh it has hit me as if it came out of the sky,now we have same isomormphism types since constructed structures are isomorphic thus they belong to same order type.Brilliant

Comment: Lucky for you that you're not a dinosaur. They all died because something hit them as if it came out of the sky! :-)

Comment: But Asaf,I have realized that the newly obtained structure,lets call it $ \langle A^{'} , R^{'} \rangle $ is not necessarily a member of original order type $\alpha$ thus we have only proven that we can construct a structure with same order type as one given,but we have not proven that it belongs to given order type.Please correct me if I am wrong,because I am hoping I am

Comment: Remember that they are isomorphic. Order type is exactly the thing which is preserved under order isomorphisms.

Comment: Yes I know,but lets say that $\alpha = it \langle P,Q \rangle$ it is still not a guarantee that $ \langle P,Q \rangle \in \alpha $,if we obey the definitions I have laid out in main post

Comment: Well, first of all, note that this is talking about isomorphism types. So it has to be preserved by isomorphisms. Secondly, the point about the rank is not fully clear to me, but I suspect that the meaning in the context of well-orders is simply that a well order is not isomorphic to its proper initial segments (without saying that).

Comment: Yeah it really is hard to grasp ,I tried writing down the isomorphism type of well ordered set of 1 ,I failed due to complexity of definition.Thing about ranks is like insurance that it is well defined aka that isomorphism type still makes a set and not a class,since all its members have to have same rank.Thank you anyhow,now I am starting to feel a bit embarased for "harassing" you this long.

Comment: Ah, don't worry about it.