# Enderton's isomorphism type arithmetic

Tags: elementary-set-theory

On page 222 in Enderton's Elements of Set Theory, there's a remark which is then justified as an exercise:

> Show that for any order types $\rho$ and $\sigma$ there exist structures $\langle A,R\rangle$ and $\langle B,S\rangle$ of types $\rho$ and $\sigma$, respectively, such that $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

This question is related to [There exist $\langle A,R \rangle $ and $\langle B,S \rangle $ of order types $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with A and B disjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920862/there-exist-langle-a-r-rangle-and-langle-b-s-rangle-of-order-types-a).

Essentially the isomorphism type of a partially ordered set $\langle A,<\rangle$ is the set of all partially ordered sets which are order isomorphic to $\langle A,<\rangle$ and has the least rank.

Enderton claims that we can find disjoint members from any pair of isomorphism types. I find it hard to prove this (which is a foundational for defining order type arithmetic).

NOTE: the isomorphic equivalence class is too large to be a set but Enderton used Scott's trick to make a set. Now Enderton is working with it for isomorphism type arithmetic, but the detail about finding disjoint members from any two iso-types is too elusive for me.

Can I get insight as to the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** The proof is based on two parts:

1. If $A$ and $B$ are two sets, then there is some $A'$ such that $|A|=|A'|$ and $A'\cap B=\varnothing$.
2. If $f\colon X\to Y$ is a given bijection (*any* given bijection), and $R$ is a relation on $X$, then there is some $R'$ such that $f$ is an isomorphism between $\langle X,R\rangle$ and $\langle Y,R'\rangle$.

Comment: Both parts are not difficult when you think about them. But I'll be happy to elaborate on specific parts if you want me to.

Comment: If $(A,\prec_A)\in it(A^*,\prec_0)$ and $(B,\prec_B)\in it(B^*,\prec_1)$, then I agree that I can find $(A',\prec_{A'})$ which is order isomorphic to $(A,\prec_A)$ and disjoint from $B$. But is $(A',\prec_{A'})$ in the isomorphism type of $(A^*,\prec_0)$? They have equal isomorphism type (because they're isomorphic) but that's not what's important. I.E. how to show it has the least rank for which it's isomorphic to $(A^*,\prec_0)$.

Comment: When you say "of type" you don't mean *members of the Scott set of the isomorphism class*, but rather "isomorphic to an element of the Scott set of the isomorphism class".

Comment: If you want to insist on rank minimality, you can *probably* show that this is false for finite partial orders, but that it is possible for infinite orders, simply because you can just "shrink" away a sufficient part whilst preserving the same cardinality (and then you apply the rank minimality to claim that you didn't decrease the rank).

Comment: This means on page 222 Enderton made a typo? "Any member of an order type $\rho$ is said to be a linearly ordered structure of type $\rho$.'' where "An order type is the iso-type of some linearly ordered structure...We will use Greek letters $\rho,\sigma,\ldots$ for order types."

Comment: Take $\alpha$ to be any countable ordinal larger than $\omega$. The least possible rank for $(X,R)$ which isomorphic to $(\alpha,\in)$ is exactly $\omega+1$ (or $\omega+5$ if you want to also include the relation itself, not just the underlying set). This meas that $\alpha$ is "not of order type $\alpha$". I have not read Enderton (I flipped through it twice, though) so I can't tell you want he meant exactly. I can tell you what it means to have the same "type" under the notion of "same cardinality" when that is modeled using Scott cardinals.

Comment: can i get a reference for a textbook where you learned order type? (developed correctly)?

Comment: Sorry, I just had excellent teachers. :-)